# Yolo from scratch dataset and output

Tags: python, numpy, keras, artificial-intelligence, yolo

Hi I coded a YOLO model from scratch and just came to realise that my dataset does not fit the models output. This is what I mean:
The model outputs a `S x S x (B * 5 + C)` matrix.
The shape of y[0] (the answer for the first image) is `(7,5)`.
How will I make the model use the labels of mine.
From what I knew and read the labels come in this format `x,y,w,h,objectiveness_score, class_scores` for the yolo algorithm so how come that the model will output a 3D matrix while the labels are a 2d matrix.

How will I solve the issue of mine by using numpy and keras?

Comment: maybe u can mention some shapes in the network, of output, of labels

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/understanding-yolo-f5a74bbc7967 I was following this guide.
The output shape of their model is 7*7*30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [paper (section 2)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf), the `S x S x (B * 5 + C)` shaped output represents the `S x S` grid cells that YoloV1 splits the image into. The last layer can be implemented as a fully connected layer with an output length `S x S x (B * 5 + C)`, then you can simply reshape the output to a 3D shape.

The paper states that:

"Our system divides the input image into an S × S grid.
If the center of an object falls into a grid cell, that grid cell
is responsible for detecting that object."

Meaning you have to assign each label to its corresponding grid cell in order to do backpropagation. For reference, a keras/tensorflow implementation of the loss calculation can be found [here](https://github.com/FMsunyh/keras-yolo/blob/master/core/layers/_losses.py) (by the github user FMsunyh).